# Blob transfer using azcopy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I am using the below PowerShell script to transfer files from azure blob in one account to another azure blob in a different Azure account. I will need to update the script to include a success.txt file to the destination blob with the Date time of the completion of upload. If there is a Success file already the script need to replace it with the latest upload time.

How do I achieve this pls can this be done with AZcopy or should I use another command.

```
# storage account details
$sourceStorageAccount = ""
$sourceContainer = ""
$sourceFolderPath = ""
$sourceSasToken = ""

# Destination details
$destStorageAccount = ""
$destContainer = ""
$destFolderPath = ""
$destSasToken = ""

# Construct source and destination container URIs
$sourceContainerUri = "https://$sourceStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$sourceContainer/$sourceFolderPath?$sourceSasToken"
$destContainerUri = "https://$destStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$destContainer/$destFolderPath?$destSasToken"

azcopy copy "$sourceContainerUri" "$destContainerUri" --recursive=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below Powershell script with az copy to add success.txt file with date and time.

```
# Delete existing success.txt file
azcopy sync "$sourceContainerUri" "$destContainerUri" --recursive=true --delete-destination=true --include-pattern="success.txt"
# Add success.txt file with the date and time
$currentDateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
azcopy copy "success.txt" "$destContainerUri" --blob-tags="upload-time=$currentDateTime"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Upload time reflected like below:-**

[image]

[image]

**Complete Powershell script:-**

```
# storage account details
$sourceStorageAccount = ""
$sourceContainer = ""
$sourceFolderPath = ""
$sourceSasToken = ""

# Destination details
$destStorageAccount = ""
$destContainer = ""
$destFolderPath = ""
$destSasToken = ""

# Construct source and destination container URIs
$sourceContainerUri = "https://$sourceStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$sourceContainer/$sourceFolderPath?$sourceSasToken"
$destContainerUri = "https://$destStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/$destContainer/$destFolderPath?$destSasToken"

# Delete existing success.txt file
azcopy sync "$sourceContainerUri" "$destContainerUri" --recursive=true --delete-destination=true --include-pattern="success.txt"

# Add success.txt file with the date and time
$currentDateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"
azcopy copy "success.txt" "$destContainerUri/success.txt" --blob-tags="upload-time=$currentDateTime"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: It does not work. Actually the source file does not have this success txt file. This has to be created in destination blob after the files are uploaded. the next time it has to be removed and updated with a new file with the latest date /time. 

I need to run the script in pipeline and saving the text file locally and uploading to destination is not an option for me, I need to create it directly in the blob.

Comment: Are you looking output like [this](https://i.imgur.com/WNSyuvc.png) does this answer your question

Comment: In source account I have two file like [this](https://i.imgur.com/1m82OG0.png) once I ran this script file has been transferred to destination account like [this](https://i.imgur.com/S4hpIjE.png) with the above output

Comment: @jeganaak I have updated solution in comments is it resolved ?

Comment: I have updated the script which is almost similar and it works
This code will delete the text file once it is uploaded to Blob 

```$currentTime = Get-Date
$Name = "success.txt"
New-Item $localPathforsuccessfile\success.txt
Set-Content $localPathforsuccessfile\success.txt $currentTime
azcopy copy $localPathforsuccessfile\* "$destContainerUri" --include-pattern 'success.txt' --recursive=true
Remove-Item $localPathforsuccessfile\success.txt```